# Format a (long) bulleted list to be scrollable

Tags: discussion, design, lists

In an attempt to format some questions (especially Minecraft crash questions) using this [guide](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9943/how-do-i-ask-a-good-minecraft-bug-crash-question), I have run into a an issue concerning listing mods.

Some users come with games with over 100 mods (like [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/189792/unloaded-minecraft-mods)) (**Update**: I attempted an edit on the previously mentioned question, but believe since the list was too long it was rejected or was a major factor for its rejection).

I started to format the list of mods as a bulleted list and boldfacing the version number. For example,

- CodeChickenCore **0.9.0.9**
- Micdoodlecore **8**
- NotEnoughItems **1.6.1.9**

The goal is to make it easier to read the mod name and version used. However this approach does not scale well; it stretches down the page for some atrocious amount of length.

I tried simply blockquoting the list but it does not scroll for many lines.

### Blockquote Long List

> - CodeChickenCore **0.9.0.9**
> - Micdoodlecore **8**
> - NotEnoughItems **1.6.1.9**
> - PowerCrystalsCore **1.1.8**
> - TConstruct-Preloader **0.0.1**
> - AppliedEnergistics-Core **rv14.finale3**
> - denLib **3.2.6**
> - OpenModsCore **@VERSION@**
> - DenEvents **1.0**
> - BuildCraft|Core **4.2.2**
> - UniversalElectricity **3.1.0.115**
> - mod_MouseTweaks **2.3.4**
> - AnimationAPI **1.1.2**
> - AppliedEnergistics **rv14.finale3**
> - Autoutils **1.0.1**
> - BiblioCraft **1.5.5**
> - Mekanism **6.0.5.46**
> - BuildCraft|Builders **4.2.2**
> - BuildCraft|Energy **4.2.2**
> - BuildCraft|Factory **4.2.2**
> - BuildCraft|Transport **4.2.2**
> - CoFHCore **2.0.0.5**
> - ForgeMultipart **1.0.0.219**
> - ThermalExpansion **3.0.0.7**
> - IC2 **2.0.260-experimental**
> - MineFactoryReloaded **1.6.4R2.7.9**
> - BigReactors **0.3.4A2**
> - Natura **2.1.14**
> - BiomesOPlenty **1.2.1**
> - BuildCraft|Silicon **4.2.2**
> - CarpentersBlocks **3.2.8.2**
> - Chisel **1.4.11**
> - CoFHLoot **2.0.0.5**
> - CoFHMasquerade **2.0.0.5**
> - CoFHSocial **2.0.0.5**
> - CoFHWorld **2.0.0.5**
> - DamageIndicatorsMod **2.9.2.3**
> - EnderStorage **1.4.3.6**
> - factorization **0.8.34**
> - MineFactoryReloaded|CompatForestryPre **1.6.4R2.7.9**
> - Forestry **2.3.1.1**
> - Railcraft **8.4.0.0**
> - DartCraft **Beta 0.2.20**
> - emashercore **1.2.3.4**
> - EnderIO **1.0.6**
> - LogisticsPipes|Main **0.7.4.dev.294**
> - Waila **1.5.2a**
> - extracells **1.6.9b**
> - ExtraUtilities **1.0.3c**
> - factorization.misc **0.8.34**
> - factorization.notify **0.8.34**
> - factorization.dimensionalSlice **0.8.34**
> - flatsigns **1.4.0.15**
> - GalacticraftCore **2.0.14.1084**
> - GalacticraftMars **2.0.14.1084**
> - pamharvestcraft **1.0**
> - Hats **2.1.8**
> - HatStand **2.1.0**
> - IronChest **5.4.1.702**
> - JABBA **1.1.4**
> - MekanismGenerators **6.0.5**
> - minechem **5.05.101**
> - MFR Compat Forestry Trees **1.0**
> - MFR Compat Extra Trees **1.0**
> - MineFactoryReloaded|CompatAppliedEnergistics **1.6.4R2.7.9**
> - MineFactoryReloaded|CompatAtum **1.6.4R2.7.9**
> - MineFactoryReloaded|CompatBackTools **1.6.4R2.7.9**
> - MineFactoryReloaded|CompatBuildCraft **1.6.4R2.7.9**
> - MineFactoryReloaded|CompatChococraft **1.6.4R2.7.9**
> - MineFactoryReloaded|CompatExtraBiomes **1.6.4R2.7.9**
> - MineFactoryReloaded|CompatForestry **1.6.4R2.7.9**
> - MineFactoryReloaded|CompatForgeMicroblock **1.6.4R2.7.9**
> - MineFactoryReloaded|CompatIC2 **1.6.4R2.7.9**
> - MineFactoryReloaded|CompatMystcraft **1.6.4R2.7.9**
> - MineFactoryReloaded|CompatPams **1.6.4R2.7.9**
> - MineFactoryReloaded|CompatProjRed **1.6.4R2.7.9**
> - MineFactoryReloaded|CompatRailcraft **1.6.4R2.7.9**
> - MineFactoryReloaded|CompatRP2 **1.6.4R2.7.9**
> - MineFactoryReloaded|CompatSufficientBiomes **1.6.4R2.7.9**
> - MineFactoryReloaded|CompatThaumcraft **1.6.4R2.7.9**
> - MineFactoryReloaded|CompatThermalExpansion **1.6.4R2.7.9**
> - MineFactoryReloaded|CompatTwilightForest **1.6.4R2.7.9**
> - MineFactoryReloaded|CompatVanilla **1.6.4R2.7.9**
> - MineFactoryReloaded|CompatXyCraft **1.6.4R2.7.9**
> - ResonantEngine **1.2.0.266**
> - MFFS **3.6.3**
> - cfm **3.3.4**
> - OpenMods **0.5.1**
> - OpenBlocks **1.2.9**
> - PluginsforForestry **3.2.30**
> - iChunUtil **2.4.0**
> - PortalGun **2.0.2**
> - secretroomsmod **4.6.2**
> - Statues **2.0.2**
> - Sync **2.2.3**
> - TConstruct **1.6.X_1.5.5.7**
> - TSteelworks **1.6.4-0.0.4.2-fix2**
> - TiCTooltips **1.1.7**
> - TMechworks **33.c001660**
> - WailaHarvestability **1.1.0**
> - mod_ZanMinimap **Not available**
> - McMultipart **1.0.0.219**
> - ForgeMicroblock **1.0.0.219**

### Preformat Long List

Then I tried preformatting where scrolling many lines is possible, but it loses the boldface and bullets:

```
- CodeChickenCore **0.9.0.9**
- Micdoodlecore **8**
- NotEnoughItems **1.6.1.9**
- PowerCrystalsCore **1.1.8**
- TConstruct-Preloader **0.0.1**
- AppliedEnergistics-Core **rv14.finale3**
- denLib **3.2.6**
- OpenModsCore **@VERSION@**
- DenEvents **1.0**
- BuildCraft|Core **4.2.2**
- UniversalElectricity **3.1.0.115**
- mod_MouseTweaks **2.3.4**
- AnimationAPI **1.1.2**
- AppliedEnergistics **rv14.finale3**
- Autoutils **1.0.1**
- BiblioCraft **1.5.5**
- Mekanism **6.0.5.46**
- BuildCraft|Builders **4.2.2**
- BuildCraft|Energy **4.2.2**
- BuildCraft|Factory **4.2.2**
- BuildCraft|Transport **4.2.2**
- CoFHCore **2.0.0.5**
- ForgeMultipart **1.0.0.219**
- ThermalExpansion **3.0.0.7**
- IC2 **2.0.260-experimental**
- MineFactoryReloaded **1.6.4R2.7.9**
- BigReactors **0.3.4A2**
- Natura **2.1.14**
- BiomesOPlenty **1.2.1**
- BuildCraft|Silicon **4.2.2**
- CarpentersBlocks **3.2.8.2**
- Chisel **1.4.11**
- CoFHLoot **2.0.0.5**
- CoFHMasquerade **2.0.0.5**
- CoFHSocial **2.0.0.5**
- CoFHWorld **2.0.0.5**
- DamageIndicatorsMod **2.9.2.3**
- EnderStorage **1.4.3.6**
- factorization **0.8.34**
- MineFactoryReloaded|CompatForestryPre **1.6.4R2.7.9**
- Forestry **2.3.1.1**
- Railcraft **8.4.0.0**
- DartCraft **Beta 0.2.20**
- emashercore **1.2.3.4**
- EnderIO **1.0.6**
- LogisticsPipes|Main **0.7.4.dev.294**
- Waila **1.5.2a**
- extracells **1.6.9b**
- ExtraUtilities **1.0.3c**
- factorization.misc **0.8.34**
- factorization.notify **0.8.34**
- factorization.dimensionalSlice **0.8.34**
- flatsigns **1.4.0.15**
- GalacticraftCore **2.0.14.1084**
- GalacticraftMars **2.0.14.1084**
- pamharvestcraft **1.0**
- Hats **2.1.8**
- HatStand **2.1.0**
- IronChest **5.4.1.702**
- JABBA **1.1.4**
- MekanismGenerators **6.0.5**
- minechem **5.05.101**
- MFR Compat Forestry Trees **1.0**
- MFR Compat Extra Trees **1.0**
- MineFactoryReloaded|CompatAppliedEnergistics **1.6.4R2.7.9**
- MineFactoryReloaded|CompatAtum **1.6.4R2.7.9**
- MineFactoryReloaded|CompatBackTools **1.6.4R2.7.9**
- MineFactoryReloaded|CompatBuildCraft **1.6.4R2.7.9**
- MineFactoryReloaded|CompatChococraft **1.6.4R2.7.9**
- MineFactoryReloaded|CompatExtraBiomes **1.6.4R2.7.9**
- MineFactoryReloaded|CompatForestry **1.6.4R2.7.9**
- MineFactoryReloaded|CompatForgeMicroblock **1.6.4R2.7.9**
- MineFactoryReloaded|CompatIC2 **1.6.4R2.7.9**
- MineFactoryReloaded|CompatMystcraft **1.6.4R2.7.9**
- MineFactoryReloaded|CompatPams **1.6.4R2.7.9**
- MineFactoryReloaded|CompatProjRed **1.6.4R2.7.9**
- MineFactoryReloaded|CompatRailcraft **1.6.4R2.7.9**
- MineFactoryReloaded|CompatRP2 **1.6.4R2.7.9**
- MineFactoryReloaded|CompatSufficientBiomes **1.6.4R2.7.9**
- MineFactoryReloaded|CompatThaumcraft **1.6.4R2.7.9**
- MineFactoryReloaded|CompatThermalExpansion **1.6.4R2.7.9**
- MineFactoryReloaded|CompatTwilightForest **1.6.4R2.7.9**
- MineFactoryReloaded|CompatVanilla **1.6.4R2.7.9**
- MineFactoryReloaded|CompatXyCraft **1.6.4R2.7.9**
- ResonantEngine **1.2.0.266**
- MFFS **3.6.3**
- cfm **3.3.4**
- OpenMods **0.5.1**
- OpenBlocks **1.2.9**
- PluginsforForestry **3.2.30**
- iChunUtil **2.4.0**
- PortalGun **2.0.2**
- secretroomsmod **4.6.2**
- Statues **2.0.2**
- Sync **2.2.3**
- TConstruct **1.6.X_1.5.5.7**
- TSteelworks **1.6.4-0.0.4.2-fix2**
- TiCTooltips **1.1.7**
- TMechworks **33.c001660**
- WailaHarvestability **1.1.0**
- mod_ZanMinimap **Not available**
- McMultipart **1.0.0.219**
- ForgeMicroblock **1.0.0.219**
```

### Bottom Line

Is there a means, through markdown or HTML, for a list to keep its rich format *and* be scrollable?

### Update

I see the difference between blockquoting and preformatting. Blockformatting lacks the ability to scroll through a lot of lines. I have added an example list. I re-worded the question.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do. Do you want a bulleted list *within* a blockquote? If so, that should be perfectly doable with regular markdown, but I'm not sure how it solves the problem of list length.

Comment: I think you're confusing blockquote with preformatted text.

Comment: If it is in a blockquote, the bullets and boldfaced text become fixed width and show the hyphens and asterisks. The idea would be to have a fixed window with the list and keeping the bullets and boldface format intact.

Comment: Doesn't blockquoting preformat the text? I couldn't find a difference.

Comment: Short answer: No.  Long answer: Not without using backticks (these fellows: ``) on each item.  i.e. `CodeChickenCore` **`0.9.0.9`** <-- This is done using backticks around CodeChickenCore and again between the `**` and version number (on both sides).

Comment: @Powerlord Would you make that an answer? It seems to be the best one so far.

Comment: Also, you don't need to surround every line with backticks. Selecting the list and hitting the '{}' markdown button will have the same effect

Comment: Preformatting each line won't achieve any scrolling. You won't get scrolling unless your also give up all other formatting.

Comment: @murgatroid99 That's what I was wondering about. It seems the answer is simply it cannot be done. Maybe there's an HTML workaround?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<pre>
  <ul>
    <li><b>test</b> <i>test</i>
    <li>a
    ...
  </ul>
</pre>
```

```
test test
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```