# Bounty button missing

Tags: support, bounty

I would like to place a bounty on [why just ban minecraft modding tech support](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10568/why-just-ban-minecraft-modding-tech-support?noredirect=1&lq=1), but I can't seem to find the button. After some research it seems like it's supposed to be under <kbd>add a comment</kbd>, but it isn't there:

[image: missing bounty button]

I have then checked and didn't find the bounty button on any other meta.arqade, or regular arqade question either. When I tried to look it up in meta.stackexchange, I noticed that the button was where I expected it to be:

[image: correctly placed bounty button in meta.stackexchange]

<sub>(Also, why isn't the button next to the <kbd>share</kbd>, <kbd>edit</kbd>, <kbd>vote</kbd>, and <kbd>flag</kbd> button?)</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[You can't start a bounty on per-site metas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77658/am-i-allowed-to-set-bounties-on-meta-sites), as those sites don't have a reputation system, they just copy the reputation of the main site. [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) *does* have its own reputation system, so bounties can be started there.

For main sites, bounties can only be started at least 24 hours after a question's creation.

Comment: After reading this, I realized that I only checked recent questions on the main site, I forgot that the question has to be at least 24 hours old. Would it be possilbe to add that to your answer to make it complete?

Comment: You can just self-answer the question if you found that the problem was something else not mentioned in any of the existing answers.

Comment: The problem was, as you explained, that it was a per-site meta. I just mentioned in the question that I looked on the regular main site, too. This is not adressed by your answer, but this additional info wouldn't really answer the question, so adding a new answer feels redundant, as it wouldn't add any nessessary information for solving the problem.