# General redirect for the same questions

Tags: discussion, minecraft

Can their be some sort of general redirect for all the kids asking about their crashed/not working Minecraft games?

I feel like 10x a day there is the same general questions from kids asking why their Minecraft crashed, a mod isn't working or the server isn't working etc etc.

Is there anyway to divert people asking those same questions to ones that have been answered?

Comment: If they're duplicates, vote to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no 'one question' which will automatically solve all of Minecraft's problems, but here's some basic guidance and relevant posts that will help:

If the question is specifically about tech support/crashes to do with modded Minecraft, Flag/Close->Off Topic, as we do not allow those here, see: [Minecraft crash questions should be made off-topic: yes/no?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10390/minecraft-crash-questions-should-be-made-off-topic-yes-no)

Otherwise if the question does not contain enough information, start by pointing them here: [How do I ask a good Minecraft Bug/Crash question?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9943/how-do-i-ask-a-good-minecraft-bug-crash-question) for more information.

We have a list of common error scenarios, so see if the Error Message is one of these: [Is there a list of error codes for Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96496/is-there-a-list-of-error-codes-for-minecraft), and Flag/Close->Duplicate if so.

Comment: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10390/minecraft-crash-questions-should-be-made-off-topic-yes-no?noredirect=1&lq=1 Hmm didn't see this one before.. thanks though